# Stop Windows Service waiting on AcceptTcpClient

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, tcpclient

I have a Windows service that listens for connections with

```
TcpClient client = myTcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
```

I am wondering what happens when this Windows service is stopped while waiting to accept a new connection.

Will the listener still be listening for connections on that port?  If so, how can I kill this listener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call [`Stop()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.stop.aspx) on the listener. Note that you need to close accepted connections separately.

Answer (score 0):

When the process dies, the listener will obviously not be listening anymore.

You should clean it up properly as mentioned by ChrisWue.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same behavior of a thread. 
The process only ends when threads finish.
When you run the stop method, close all connections manually.